# Time Stamp as key in firebase firestore document

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save data on Firebase Firestore where the key will be timestamp:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(uid)
      .collection('data')
      .doc(device.id)
      .update({
    DateTime.now().toString(): "${result['humidity']}_${result['tempInC']}"
  });
}
```

What can be the possible reasons for this nested hierarchy as shown in the image: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDWQN.png), any solution?

Comment: So to understand better, do you need to save a Date object as key inside a document in Firestore?

Comment: yeah @AlexMamo, so I can fetch the data, and delete the data later based up on the keys

Comment: What programming language are you using here?

Comment: Dart (Flutter) @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

According to my first question in the comments section:

> Do you need to save a Date object as a key inside a document in Firestore?

And your answer:

> yeah @AlexMamo

Please note that there is no way you can save a Date/Timestamp object as a key in a Firestore document. The keys are **always** strings. You can indeed convert the Date object into a String, but I don't think this is what you're looking for.

The best option I can think of would be to save the timestamp as a value and not as a key. For example, you can add a field called `addedAt` that should hold a Firestore timestamp. In this way, you'll be able to query the collection using Timestamp objects.

Comment: so all I want to add into my document is readings of some sensor after some interval. the only way I can differentiate, fetch and analyze the past readings are through timestamp. Even I'm trying to convert the timestamp into string, but in vain!

Comment: @AbdullahSaeed It is not recommended to use timestamps (converted to string) as document IDs because they are likely to be "monotonically increasing document IDs" which is [to be avoided](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices?hl=en&authuser=0#document_ids). As explained by Alex you can store the timestamp value as a field of the document and very well order your documents based on this field, as well as querying them based on the field value, for reading or deleting them.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've figured out alternative approach, where the key will be now milli_seconds_since_epoch (integer). By the way thanks

Comment: If you set the integer value as a key, it automatically becomes a string, so it makes no difference.

Comment: @AbdullahSaeed ⚠️ using now milli_seconds_since_epoch as a key may lead to [hotspots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices?hl=en&authuser=0#high_read_write_and_delete_rates_to_a_narrow_document_range) that impact latency. See my above comment.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec and AlexMamo
Thanks a lot guys

Comment: So can I help you with other information Abdullah?